# Creating another wordpress site as sub-domain of a wordpress site

Tags: wp-admin, urls, subdomains

Main domain: `www.abc.com`

new wordpress: `xyz.abc.com`

I have manage to work everything on the front-end part. both use the same database but different tables classified with their own prefixes.

problem is, I cannot access the `xyz.abc.com/wp-admin`

it always says `"You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."` after I logged in even as an admin

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why WP could display this:

1 Insufficient file permissions on wp-admin folder (check this with ftp)

2 Prefix not consistently the same in database and wp-config (less likely in this case, but check anyway).

3 .htaccess doesn't reroute wp-admin folder correctly

4 User roles not well defined in database (`wp_capabilities` should contain `a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}` and `wp_user_level` should read `10`)

5 All sorts of plugin screw ups.

For debugging you can use this snippet of code in `functions.php` to gain access. It bypasses the persmission system, so don't forget to remove it once you're done.

```
function wpse227971_skip_permissions ( $allcaps, $cap, $args ) {
    $allcaps[$cap[0]] = true;
    return $allcaps;
    }
add_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'wpse227971_skip_permissions', 0, 3 );
```